# The spy who confused me

Tags: steganography, cryptic-clues

"Sir! We just got a message from our undercover agent.", tones a private.

"Well, what does it say?", replies the general.

"We're not sure, sir. It doesn't make any sense.", answers the private.

Looking at you the general hands you this message. "Figure it out!", he shouts.

> RECORD = 35329199
>
> Message Locale... Chaotic Transship Helix
>
> > (Report card from blind train: Add with series of instructions.) STOP.
> >     (Dirty period of history expressed in communiqué.) STOP.
>
> RECORD# - 35329199

This record is nonsensical. What were they actually trying to say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Sconibulus got the middle cryptics](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/48939/18250):

> First is transcript, second is message. See [his answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/48939/18250) for why. The enumerations are the word counts for each, 10 and 7.

<strike>First</strike> Final* part:

The first cryptic clue is

> Message Locale... Chaotic Transship Helix

The answer is

> An anagram (chaotic) of 'Transship Helix' which is The Sphinx's Lair. So the message is located in the sphinx's lair.

So we have

> TRANSCRIPT MESSAGE THE SPHINX'S LAIR - indicating the message is in the sphinx's lair (site chatroom)

Now...

> The '35329199' indicates the message number. Going to http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35329199#35329199 give us the message:

> 'There, I give up. Too much work..'  by Sid

<sub>*Apparently I have skipped straight to the end and find the final answer without actually doing the rest of the puzzle... oops!</sub>

Comment: Everything is correct. :)

Answer (score 5):

The answer @BeastlyGerbil already found, but I've got the solutions to intermediate cryptics, the enumerations of which were their wordcounts.

Report card from blind train: Add with series of instructions.

> TRANSCRIPT: Def: Report Card Wordplay: TRA(-I)N+SCRIPT(10)

Dirty period of history expressed in communiqué.

> MESSAGE: Def: Communiqué Wordplay: MESS+AGE(7)